# How to optimize this nested SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle10g, query-optimization

I have a very slow query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    (
         SELECT ..., nn_key_fast(nachname) nnk, ...
         FROM   t1
           JOIN t2 ON
               ...
           JOIN t3 ON
               ...
           JOIN t4 ON
               ...
         WHERE  ...
         AND t4.POSTCODE='1234'
        )
WHERE  ... AND nnk LIKE "N%"
```

Now, the inner select takes ~2min. If I remove the last WHERE clause (t4.POSTCODE), it executes in ~4secs. The result without this clause will be < 1000 records, so a really small set.

So, my thought was: move that clause to the outside SELECT, then it will only be applied to the resulting <1000 records.

But no. The query takes exactly as long, so to be clear:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    (
         SELECT  .....
         FROM    t1
           JOIN  t2 ON
                 ...
           JOIN t3 ON
                 ...
           JOIN t4 ON
                 ...
         WHERE   ... 
        )
WHERE  ...
AND POSTCODE='1234'
```

takes the same 2 minutes that the first version takes.

This seems insane to me.

Intuitively, this must be executed by the query optimizer like this:
Create a table from the inner select as in:

```sql
CREATE TABLE res_from_inner AS (
                                SELECT .....
                                FROM t1
                                  JOIN t2 ON
                                       ...
                                  JOIN t3 ON
                                       ...
                                  JOIN t4 ON
                                       ...
                                WHERE ... 
                               )
```

... and then do the outer select only on this table, like this:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    res_from_inner
WHERE   POSTCODE='1234'
```

And if I do this manually, the CREATE TABLE query takes ~4sec, and the second SELECT takes, as expected < 1sec.

How is this possible, and what to do about it?

Comment: I guess postcode is not included in your index.

Comment: What is in the select clause of the subquery --> `SELECT .....` ? If you use any functions or expressions (like `to_char( x ) as y` or `x+y as z`) in the SELECT clause, the results of which yoou then use in the WHERE  clause (like `y = '123' or z=22`, then Oracle cannot push predicates down to the subquery, indexes are useless and it must be slow. Without details, it's difficult to advise anything here, please show the full query and it's [execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL94702), for now I vote to close your question as too broad.

Comment: @krokodilko: Feel a bit stupid right now... you are right, there is a function in the select clause, and the calculated field is used in the outer select. However, when I execute the whole query, today it takes 13 seconds... BUT: if I create a table from that select (create table as...), it takes 2 minutes again. And there are only about 1000 records in the result set. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not sure what I'm actually asking anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the execution plans to see what is really happening.  Something is changing.

One thing you might try is a CTE:

```
with s as (
      <subquery here>
     )
select s.*
from s
where . . .;
```

Oracle might automatically materialize this.  Or you can give a hint:

```
with s as (
      select /*+ materialize */ . . .
      . . .
     )
select s.*
from s
where . . .;
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Never used WITH before but this seems fairly straightforward. But also never heard of the materialize-hint, which seems to have become unnecessary since V10g (according to this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialize_sql_hint.htm). Interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I try to stay away from nested select statements. In this case, I'd have the inner select statement as a subquery and then select what I want from it.

with subquery as (
  select...from...join...join...join...where
)

select* from subquery

--hope that helps :]

Comment: Thanks. Will try to refactor my nested selects (we use them a lot) in the future into WITH CTEs. This looks much cleaner.